# Why does redirecting output to a file produce a table?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, curl

I would like to setup a cron job to periodically record a measurement.  A USB memory stick is installed in a router:

```
user@router:/tmp/home/root# uname -a
```

> Linux router 2.6.36.4brcmarm #2 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 20 16:06:18 EDT
>   2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
user@router:/tmp/home/root# curl http://THERMOSTAT/tstat/humidity  >> /tmp/mnt/USBstick/CT80_data/C14HumidityData.txt

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    18    0    18    0     0     80      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    83
```

Why does appending (>>) the output to a file produce the above table?

The table is not produced when not appending:

```
curl http://THERMOSTAT/tstat/humidity
{"humidity":51.00}
```

Is there a command option to suppress the table response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's curl's *progress meter*. From `man curl`

> ```
> PROGRESS METER
>    curl  normally displays a progress meter during operations, indicating the
>    amount of transferred data, transfer speeds and estimated time left,  etc.
>    The  progress  meter  displays number of bytes and the speeds are in bytes
>    per second. The suffixes (k, M, G, T, P) are 1024 based. For example 1k is
>    1024 bytes. 1M is 1048576 bytes.
>
>    curl  displays this data to the terminal by default, so if you invoke curl
>    to do an operation and it is about to write data to the terminal, it  dis‐
>    ables  the  progress meter as otherwise it would mess up the output mixing
>    progress meter and response data.
>
>    If you want a progress meter for HTTP POST or PUT requests,  you  need  to
>    redirect  the  response  output  to  a file, using shell redirect (>), -o,
>    --output or similar.
>
>    It is not the same case for FTP upload as that operation does not spit out
>    any response data to the terminal.
>
>    If  you  prefer  a  progress  "bar"  instead  of  the  regular  meter, -#,
>    --progress-bar is your friend. You can also  disable  the  progress  meter
>    completely with the -s, --silent option.
> ```